# using jquery and sortable how to tell if user starts to move and puts it back

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a UL list with a much of li's
i am using

```
            $( "#group" ).sortable({
                start: function(event, ui) {
                },
                stop: function(event, ui) {
                    enableSave();
                }
            });
```

What i would like to do is--> if the person starts to move the LI and decides to put it back NOT to call enableSave();

I thought i could save event.pageX and pageY and  then check on the stop , but although the item is put back in the same place that value is never exactly the same

I am sure there is a correct way to do this

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.index()` to get the index of the `li` in the `ul`. Store the starting `index` on start and then compare it to the index at the end. If it's the same, it ain't moved :)

Answer (score 0):

When the start function is called you could get the position of the element (top and left), when the stop function is called, get the position again and check if it's the same. If it's not then it's been moved.